# Create a System.IO.Stream from Memory<byte>

Tags: c#, memorystream

Why there's no `new MemoryStream(Memory<byte> buffer)` or  `new MemoryStream(ReadonlyMemory<byte> buffer)`? What are the workaround besides reallocating a new byte array ?

I've an API expecting a `Stream` to do some parsing :

```
var parsed = HeartbeatMessage.Parse(Stream stream) ;
```

Note : it's from Bouncy Castle c#.

I have the actual data under a `Memory<byte>` and I just expect to make a call like this

```
Memory<byte> buffer = .... // data 
var parsed =  HeartbeatMessage.Parse(new MemoryStream(buffer));
```

Comment: Because the whole point of using `Memory<byte>` is to *avoid* copying bytes around, returning `Span<>`s instead that reference the bytes. There are `Memory<byte>` backed implementations though, and even stream pools. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You could check for example [Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream](https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream) which offers streams built over pooled buffers. When you use a Stream's `Read` though, you'll still copy the actual bytes.

Comment: Any duplicate that points to a Windows-specific package isn't a good duplicate

Comment: I'm sorry for the duplicate but I didn't find it the duplicate from the search engine

Comment: The duplicate was for some helpers in the Windows Community Toolkit. You haven't explained what you want though. `RecyclableMemoryStream` and other similar packages will give you pools of streams. That's probably what you need. If you want to avoid copying buffers altogether though you'll have to use [Pipelines API](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/).

Comment: And that linked toolkit was discontinued anyway. The code was moved to [CommunityToolkit](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet) which offers an [AsStream(Memory<byte>)](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/blob/017a4710b5aeacf98acf8d0fbfa771954f525014/src/CommunityToolkit.HighPerformance/Extensions/MemoryExtensions.cs#L108) extension method. Whether that's useful or not depends on your use case. Can you get by with a single `Memory<T>` instance for the entire application lifetime? Or do you need a pool of reusable ones?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm checking this package currently. I'm not the owner of `Memory<byte>`, a caller will provide the  buffer. I'm looking also if I can use `MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray` to retrieve back the original `byte[]`  but I really don't see yet in which case it returns false